# calculate duration between intervals of 15 minute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, row

so i've been trying to find an answer for a problem i have.
i have a client with call information table.
the table look  like this:
[image: original table]
and he want me to create a new table that splits every record to hour quarters (0-15,15-30,30-45,45-60) and using the login time and duration of the call calculate for each row how many seconds in each hour quarter he was in the agentsate. so if he was in a talking state for 120 seconds(duration column) and he started talking on logindatetime of 14.3.18 11:44 i should add two columns to the new table for each quarter in the hour and what was the duration for it.
something like this
[image: newtable]
does anyone have an idea?
i thought about a cursor but i dont understand how to do it and it sounds like its going to have a big impact on performance.
the duration in seconds can be up to a day, not only minutes or seconds.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please always include (via a tag) the version of SQL Server. Also, it's not quite clear what you're after. If the user started at 11:44 and you want to report duration per each 15-minute period, shouldn't there be a row for 11:30-11:45, representing the first minute they were talking, and another row for 11:45-12:00, representing the second minute they were talking? If that new column is only needed to represent which quarter hour the activity *started* in, this calculation is a lot simpler than you're making it sound.

Comment: what im trying to understand is how to calculate the results of duration in every 15 minutes.. like if it starts at 16:30 and ends in 16:52 how do i get new rows for every quarter like this: hour quarter 30-45, duration 15(in seconds but doesnt matter) and then another row : hour quarter 45-60 duration 7

Comment: and the rows arent only for calls it can be on a break, talking, not ready, ready etc

Comment: @AaronBertrand i'm sorry i don't know how to edit my comments so i'm tagging you like this.

Comment: I still don't understand the data. The first two rows show duration of 135 and then 130 for the same login start time. Which happened first? How do we know? Why aren't you tracking start and end time of each event?

Comment: @AaronBertrand the tables in the post is not of the same example.. my bad. it just ment to show how the new table should look like.

Comment: the first table is tracking the start date and the duration (and i just add the duration to the start date for the end date)

Comment: I would store the end date. It makes more sense to track the end points and calculate the duration than storing one or the other. But really, your question should include *real* sample data and *real* desired results, so that anyone trying to write a query knows if it actually solves your problem. Your data doesn't technically have to be real, but it should be realistic.

Comment: its a client with a shelf product he wont let me change existing tables only add new ones.. i think i found a way to do this using cte but now i get too many rows.. maybe ill open a new question with the cte. thank you anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand youre right. its my bad.

Comment: That is not the actual output you desire?  Come on show some effort.   Please post text data and desired output.  You can see my answer to this question for formatting option.  https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/format-for-data-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this data:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.AgentLog
(
  AgentID int,
  AgentState varchar(32),
  LoginDateTime datetime,
  Duration int
);

INSERT dbo.AgentLog VALUES
(5045,'TALKING',   '20180318 11:44',130),
(5045,'WORK_READY','20180318 11:47',1200),
(5046,'READY',     '20180318 12:45',1800),
(5046,'TALKING',   '20180318 13:15',1801),
(5047,'READY',     '20180318 12:59',12000);
```

The way I thought about the problem is that you need to identify all the 15 time slots possible. Since you say no duration will last more than 24 hours, this means you need 96 time slots, plus one at the end to handle the end of any range.

Now, in order to distribute a call over 15-minute blocks, you need to join against all these time slots. There are either two or three categories of matching here, depending on the exact start/end time of any activity:

1. the 15-minute interval where the activity begins
2. any 15-minute interval completely encompassed by the activity
3. the 15-minute interval where the activity ends

For 1., we measure the duration by the number of seconds that elapse between **the start of the activity** and **the end of that first interval**.

For 2., we measure the duration by the length of the interval.

For 3., we measure the duration by the number of seconds that elapse between **the start of that last interval** and **the end of the activity**.

So my query looks like this:

```
;WITH Activity AS 
(
  SELECT *, aStart = LoginDateTime, aEnd = DATEADD(SECOND, Duration, LoginDateTime)
  FROM dbo.AgentLog
), ARanges AS
(
  SELECT *, 
    ASRange = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS
    (YEAR(a.aStart),MONTH(a.aStart),DAY(a.aStart),DATEPART(HOUR,a.aStart),DATEPART(MINUTE,a.aStart)/15*15),
    AERange = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS
    (YEAR(a.aEnd),MONTH(a.aEnd),DAY(a.aEnd),DATEPART(HOUR,a.aEnd),DATEPART(MINUTE,a.aEnd)/15*15)
  FROM Activity AS a
), RealRanges AS
(
  SELECT *, 
    RSRange = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15*fifteen.rn, ARanges.ASRange),
    RERange = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15*(fifteen.rn+1), ARanges.ASRange)
    FROM ARanges 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT TOP (97) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
      FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
    ) AS fifteen
    ON fifteen.rn <= DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ARanges.ASRange, ARanges.AERange)/15
)
SELECT AgentID, AgentState, LoginDateTime, Duration, QuarterHour = DATEPART(HOUR, RSRange),
    Abbreviation = CONCAT(DATEPART(MINUTE, RSRange) ,'-', DATEPART(MINUTE, RERange)),
    QuarterHourDuration = CASE 
      WHEN RSRange <= aStart THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, aStart, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, RSRange)) 
      WHEN RERange >= aEnd THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, RSRange, aEnd) 
      ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, RSRange, RERange)
    END
 FROM RealRanges
 WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND, RSRange, aEnd) > 0;
```

Comment: hi can you explain what you did in the realranges aranges please? i dont really understand the calculation.. i found a problem with this query when inserting a duration under a minute and when i add other clumns to the first table. :( thanks

Comment: like for example why are you doing the /15*15

Comment: @winter_sql It's to round, using integer math, to 15 minutes. If you're changing the problem, it's possible you need a new solution. Please always ask the problem you have, without "dumbing it down."

Answer (score 1):

3 Step approach:

1. generate the intervals.
2. match calls against overlapping ranges
3. figure the duration of each call within that range

> ```
> create table #calls 
> (id int not null identity primary key, 
> starttime datetime, 
> duration int)
>
> insert into #calls (starttime, duration) values 
> ('2018-05-14 8:33:00', 45) -- 1 period
> ,('2018-05-14 8:42:00', 460) -- 2 periods
> ,('2018-05-14 8:55:00', 3500) -- 5 periods
>
> --Assume table [Number] (N int) with rows 1 to 1 mil. 
> ;
> with Intervals as 
> (select top (150000) dateadd(mi, n*15, '2018-01-01') interval_start, 
> dateadd(mi, n*15+15, '2018-01-01') interval_end 
> from Number order by N)
> select * , 
>
> case
> --Full 15 min 
> when starttime <= interval_start and dateadd(ss, duration, c.starttime) >=  interval_end 
> then 15*60
> -- partial, overlapping start
> when starttime <= interval_start and dateadd(ss, duration, c.starttime) <  interval_end 
> then datediff(ss, interval_start, dateadd(ss, duration, c.starttime))
> -- partial, overlapping end
> when starttime > interval_start and dateadd(ss, duration, c.starttime) >= interval_end 
> then datediff(ss, c.starttime, interval_end)
> -- partial, wholly contained
> when starttime > interval_start and dateadd(ss, duration, c.starttime) < interval_end 
> then duration
> else null
> end  interval_duration
>
> from #calls c inner join Intervals 
> on dateadd(ss, duration, c.starttime) >= interval_start 
> and c.starttime < interval_end
>
>
> go
>
> drop table #calls
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To me the requirements are not clear.  But this is a try.

```
declare @t table (agent int, task char(1), logTm datetime, dur smallint);
insert into @t values 
       (100, 'a', '2000-010-01 09:01', 10)
     , (100, 'a', '2000-010-01 09:02', 10)
     , (100, 'b', '2000-010-01 09:08', 15)
     , (100, 'a', '2000-010-01 09:16', 11)
     , (100, 'a', '2000-010-01 09:17', 12)
     , (100, 'b', '2000-010-01 09:18', 17)
     , (100, 'c', '2000-010-01 09:36', 11)
     , (100, 'c', '2000-010-01 09:37', 12)
     , (100, 'c', '2000-010-01 09:38', 17);
with cte as 
(
select t.agent, cast(t.logTm as date) dt
     , datepart(hour, t.logTm) as hr 
     , t.task
     , datepart(MINUTE, t.logTm) / 15 as qtr
     , q.name 
     , t.dur
from @T t 
join ( values (0, '0-14'), (1, '15-29'), (2, '30-44'), (3, '45-59') 
     ) q(id, name)
  on datepart(MINUTE, t.logTm) / 15 = q.id 
) 
select t.agent, t.task, t.dt, t.hr, t.name, sum(t.dur) as dur 
from cte t
group by t.agent, t.dt, t.hr, t.qtr, t.task, t.name 
order by t.agent, t.dt, t.hr, t.qtr, t.task; 

agent       task dt         hr          name  dur
----------- ---- ---------- ----------- ----- -----------
100         a    2000-10-01 9           0-14  20
100         b    2000-10-01 9           0-14  15
100         a    2000-10-01 9           15-29 23
100         b    2000-10-01 9           15-29 17
100         c    2000-10-01 9           30-44 40
```

Comment: Thank you this really really helped. its what i needed pretty much!

Comment: it really helped but didnt split to seconds the duration

Comment: @GilDeWinter Question was not clear on that.  Answer is only as good as the question.

Comment: yeah youre right i wasnt clear enough.

Comment: thanks alot for helping anyway it was helpful. sorry i wasnt clear